# Understanding how parameters are passed to functions in Assembly

Tags: c, assembly

I am reading this [writeup](http://shellblade.net/docs/ret2libc.pdf) on how to perform a `ret2libc` exploit.  It states that the arguments passed to a function are stored at `ebp+8`.

Now, if I take a simple C program

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  system("/bin/sh");
}
```

And compile it:
`gcc -m32 -o test_sh test_sh.c`

and look at the disassembly of it with
`objdump -d -M intel test_sh`

```
0804840b <main>:
 804840b:       8d 4c 24 04             lea    ecx,[esp+0x4]
 804840f:       83 e4 f0                and    esp,0xfffffff0
 8048412:       ff 71 fc                push   DWORD PTR [ecx-0x4]
 8048415:       55                      push   ebp
 8048416:       89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
 8048418:       51                      push   ecx
 8048419:       83 ec 04                sub    esp,0x4
 804841c:       83 ec 0c                sub    esp,0xc
 804841f:       68 c4 84 04 08          push   0x80484c4
 8048424:       e8 b7 fe ff ff          call   80482e0 <system@plt>
 8048429:       83 c4 10                add    esp,0x10
 804842c:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
 8048431:       8b 4d fc                mov    ecx,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4]
 8048434:       c9                      leave  
 8048435:       8d 61 fc                lea    esp,[ecx-0x4]
 8048438:       c3                      ret    
 8048439:       66 90                   xchg   ax,ax
 804843b:       66 90                   xchg   ax,ax
 804843d:       66 90                   xchg   ax,ax
 804843f:       90                      nop
```

The line

```
804841f:       68 c4 84 04 08          push   0x80484c4
```

Pushes the address of the string "/bin/sh" onto the stack.  Immediately afterwards the `system@plt` function is called.  So how does one arrive to `ebp+8` from the above output?

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: simple C program and use `system` seems very weird this will create a fork

Comment: Read the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) & [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) relevant to your system (and C compiler)

Comment: Also, use `gcc -m32 -S -fverbose-asm` to get the `.s` assembler file.

Comment: This is not how parameters are passed to functions in assembly, this is specifically a calling convention known as `cdecl`. Pascal will do it differently, and some functions can be optimized to use registers instead of placing parameters in the stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The arguments passed to a function are stored at ebp+8.

That's from the ***called*** function's point of view, not from the ***calling*** function's point of view.  The calling function has its own arguments at `ebp+8`, and your `main()` does not use any of its arguments, hence, you don't see any use of `ebp+8` in your `main()`.

You can see `ebp+8` being used as follows:

- Try writing a second function, with arguments, and calling it from `main()`, instead of invoking `system()`.  You still won't see any use of `ebp+8` within `main()`, but you will see it being used in your second function.
- Try declaring your `main()` to accept its `char** argv` argument, then try sending `argv[0]` to `printf()`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't because EBP + 8 is only relevant after the prologue in system@plt after creating a new procedure frame.

```
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
```

at this point in system@plt the contents of memory location pointed to by EBP + 8 will equal 0x80484C4.